# При выгрузке в эксель добавляются лишние строки

Tags: база-данных, delphi, excel, запрос

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно сделать выгрузку в эксель запросом. Нужно выгрузить с 1 по 31 число в каждый столбец данные, выгружает правильно, но при добавлении следующей строки делает отступ на 31 стоку, а после этого добавляет следующую строку, не могу понять как это переделать.

```
   while not qAny.EOF do begin
          Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item[rowInd,1].Value:=Fields[0].Value;
          Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item[rowInd,2].Value:='ААА32587L';
           for i:=0 to 30 do begin
   Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item[rowInd-i,i+4].Value:=Fields[1].Value;inc(rowInd);
          Next;
        end; end;
```

Comment: В цикле `FOR` у Вас вычисляется номер строки `rowInd-i`, обе переменных инкрементируются на 1 за каждый проход и в результате получается, что все 31 раз вы заносите данные в одну и ту же строку. Но счетчик `rowInd` растет и с новой итерацией `WHILE` Вы попадаете в строку со сдвигом в 31.

Comment: Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как это можно исправить?

```
while not qAny.EOF do
begin
  Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item[rowInd,1].Value:=Fields[0].Value;
  Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item[rowInd,2].Value:='ААА32587L';
  for i:=0 to 30 do 
  begin
    Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item[rowInd, i+4].Value := Fields[1].Value;
    Next;
  end;
  inc(rowInd);
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает